# How and where to detect that a custom UIView size dynamically changed and adjust a scrollview accordingly?

Tags: ios, swift

iOS 9+, Swift 3.0

There are three classes:

1. `CustomTextField`. It can have two states: `error` and `normal`. This class inherits from UIView. It has a `stackView`. That `stackView` has a `UITextField` and a `UILabel` that displays an error if needed. The validation and behaviour in case of error is hidden in this class. When there is an error, the stackView get's the `UILabel` view added and it grows in height.
2. `BaseViewController`, it has a scrollView. It implements the behaviour of scrolling up a view if a keyboard appears.
3. `ImplementationViewController`. It inherits from `BaseViewController` and has a property of type `CustomTextField`.

When in the `ImplementationViewController` a user taps on the `CustomTextField`, a keyboard comes up and the `CustomTextField` is scrolled up right above the keyboard.

When the keyboard is visible, if user types an erroneous text, then an error slides down from the bottom of the `CustomTextField`.

How and where to implement the behaviour to move the scroll view up when the `CustomTextField` shows an error; and move the scroll view down when the error is being hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Create a protocol **CustomTextFieldDelegate** and inside it add a method call it **InformImplemntation** and declare delegate variable in **CustomTextField** class

CustomTextField().delegate = self [ImplementationViewController]

and when there is an error or not call delegate method and from ImplementationViewController as it inherits from **BaseViewController** manage whether to hide/show keyboard

Comment: The `CustomTextField` already has a delegate: `weak var delegate: UITextfieldDelegate? { get { return textField.delegate} set { textField.delegate = newValue} }`

Comment: And I'm wondering if there is any cleaner solution. This would result in having two delegates.